# Saving float from seekbar using dialogue preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, dialog-preference

I'm using a custom dialog preference to generate a seekbar in my preferences menu.
After researching seekbar implementation, to obtain the float value I need from the seekbar I have written the following code:

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int newValue,
        boolean fromTouch) {
    // Round the value to the closest integer value.
    if (stepSize >= 1) {
        value = Math.round(newValue/stepSize)*stepSize;

    }
    else {
        value = newValue;
    }

    // Set the valueText text.
    float sValue = newValue*10;
    sValue = sValue/100;

    valueText.setText(Float.toString(sValue));
```

Which produces the float that I want. However, I want to be able to use this float in my main activity. I have attempted to store it using SharedPreferences using:

```
userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
Editor editor = userPrefs.edit()
editor.putFloat("mpm", sValue);
editor.commit();
```

Which is how I've learned to use SharedPreferences in a class extending Activity.

However as this seekbar extends Dialogue Preference I cannot use

getBaseContext()

As I get the error that the method getBaseContext is undefined for this type.

I have tried changing getBaseContext() to getContext() but this has been unsuccessful although that may be because I am unfamiliar with this implementation.

How can I save this float from the dialogue preference and use the value in a different class?

The code I am using to retrieve SharedPreferences:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logbook);
    initialise();
    userPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    list = userPrefs.getString("list", "10");
    userswallstring = userPrefs.getString("height", "10.0");


    try {
        usersWall = Float.valueOf(userswallstring.trim());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    mpm = userPrefs.getFloat("mpm", 2);
```

Mpm.class:
     package com.gbclimber.ep;

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;

 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.content.res.TypedArray;
 import android.preference.DialogPreference;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

 import android.util.AttributeSet;

 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;

 import android.widget.SeekBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class Mpm extends
    DialogPreference implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
// Layout widgets.
private SeekBar seekBar = null;
private TextView valueText = null;

// Custom xml attributes.
private int maximumValue = 0;
private int minimumValue = 0;
private int stepSize = 0;
private String units = null;

private int value = 0;
SharedPreferences userPrefs;
/**
 * The SeekBarDialogPreference constructor.
 * @param context of this preference.
 * @param attrs custom xml attributes.
 */
public Mpm(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
        R.styleable.Mpm);

    maximumValue = typedArray.getInteger(
        R.styleable.Mpm_maximumValue, 0);
    minimumValue = typedArray.getInteger(
        R.styleable.Mpm_minimumValue, 0);
    stepSize = typedArray.getInteger(
        R.styleable.Mpm_stepSize, 1);
    units = typedArray.getString(
        R.styleable.Mpm_units);

    typedArray.recycle();
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected View onCreateDialogView() {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(
        R.layout.mpmdp, null);

    seekBar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    valueText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.valueText);

    // Get the persistent value and correct it for the minimum value.
    value = getPersistedInt(minimumValue) - minimumValue;

    // You're never know...
    if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
    }

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar.setKeyProgressIncrement(stepSize);
    seekBar.setMax(maximumValue - minimumValue);
    seekBar.setProgress(value);

    return view;
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek, int newValue,
        boolean fromTouch) {
    // Round the value to the closest integer value.
    if (stepSize >= 1) {
        value = Math.round(newValue/stepSize)*stepSize;

    }
    else {
        value = newValue;
    }

    // Set the valueText text.
    float sValue = newValue*10;
    sValue = sValue/100;
    userPrefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
    editor.putFloat("mpm", sValue);
    editor.commit();
    valueText.setText(Float.toString(sValue));

    callChangeListener(value);
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seek) {
}
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // if the positive button is clicked, we persist the value.
    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
        if (shouldPersist()) {
            persistInt(value + minimumValue);
        }
    }

    super.onClick(dialog, which);
}
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    persistInt(value + minimumValue);
}
```

}

Comment: `getContext()` should be correct. Do you receive an error for this?

Comment: No, this removes the error but doesn't seem to save a value when I try and retrieve it in my other class.

Comment: Have you verified that `commit()` is being called? Can you edit your post and show the code you are using to `get` the preference?

Comment: I've added the code where I get the preference. How can I verify that commit() is called? The next line of code appears to get called as a text view is update.

Comment: Change that `getBaseContext()` to `this`. And you can verify that `commit()` is being called by outputting to the console (using `Log`) after it is called.

Comment: using this I get this error: `The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments`

Comment: Where is this `onCreate` method? It's in an `Activity`, right?

Comment: Yes it is an Activity that is extended in another class.

Comment: After "*not applicable for the arguments*", it should say something else. What does it say? It doesn't make sense to have this error as `Activity` extends `Context`.

Comment: my class name Mpm, which is the class name.

Comment: Can you show the class declaration?

Comment: I've attached the entire class.

Comment: Ah, see, `Mpm` extends `DialogPreference`, not `Activity`. Use `getContext()` in this case, too, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a quick search but for your context try

```
this.getDialog().getContext()
```

Comment: When I use this code the seekbar dialogue will not open. Logcat output is:    failed to handle callback interface not implemented.